# All value of the variable cleared after calling canvas.childern.clear() function in windows phone?

Tags: c#, canvas, silverlight, windows-phone

I am trying to get value of variable stored before calling this.canvasname.childern.clear(); . But when I call the clear() method, everything wipes out and I got the value of the variable as '0'. Is there any Idea to get value of the variable after calling clear function?

```
this.myGrid.Children.Clear();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get the value after you've removed the control? You can store the value just before calling `Clear`.

Comment: How to store such that Value would not cleared after calling Clear()

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the controls in a list:

```
var controls = this.myGrid.Children.ToList();
```